# Subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ denote the multiplicative group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Is there a finite commutative group $G$ such that for all $n\geq 2$, there is no injective group homomorphism $f:G\to (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. By Dirichlet's theorem on primes in progressions, for each $n$ and $k$, there are at least $k$ primes $p_1,\dots,p_k$ congruent to $1$ modulo $n$, and so $$\left(\mathbb Z/ \left(\prod_{i=1}^k p_i\right) \mathbb Z\right)^\times$$ contains $(\mathbb Z/n)^k$ as a subgroup.

By the classification of finite commutative groups, every finite commutative group embeds into $(\mathbb Z/n)^k$ for some $n$ and $k$.

Answer (score 4):

Every finite abelian group $G$ is isomorphic to a product of the form
$$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}\Z/n_1\Z\times\dots\times\Z/n_k\Z.$$
Using Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions (actually, a special case which can be proven elementarily using cyclotomic polynomials) pick primes $p_i$ such that $p_i\equiv 1\pmod n_i$ and let $n=p_1\dots p_k$. Then, by Chinese remainder theorem and cyclicity of $(\Z/p\Z)^*$,
$$(\Z/n\Z)^*\cong(\Z/p_1\Z)^*\times\dots\times(\Z/p_k\Z)^*\cong\Z/(p_1-1)\Z\times\dots\times\Z/(p_k-1)\Z.$$
Since $n_i\mid p_i-1$, clearly $G$ embeds into $(\Z/n\Z)^*$.